# Horizontally center text in row with floats on both sides, with flexbox?

Tags: css, layout, center, flexbox

Here's a CSS puzzle for you all.

I'm using flexbox in **my layout**. I have a header with a few buttons on the left side, some text in the center, and another button on the right. Here's an ascii drawing:

`[btn][btn2][btn3][                text                ][btn4]`

Unfortunately, this looks weird because the text isn't centered in the header. **What I really want** is this:

`[btn][btn2][btn3][         text                       ][btn4]`

Ideally, I'd like to continue using flexbox to achieve this because it makes most of the horizontal layout really easy, but I'm willing to fall back to floats and/or positioning if need be.

One problem with positioning the text element absolutely is that long text will under/overlap the buttons on the side. I currently use text-overflow: ellipsis and as **a bonus**, I would love to continue to if possible:

`[btn][btn2][btn3][ long text causes elli...           ][btn4]`

I'm also okay with adding extra container elements if that helps. Perhaps there's a way to solve this by adding left buttons and right buttons in containers and then ensuring those containers are always the same width?

**Edit:** I think I took a step in the right direction with [this CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPpPyb?editors=110). It properly centers the text. The only downside is that the h1 needs a fixed or percentage width, and if that width is wider than the space available, it seems to just overlap the neighboring elements.

Answer (score 1):

You came very close to a working sample. I forked your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPpPyb?editors=110) with a solution that don't require widths of any kind. It's using the power of `flex` to position elements.

The `H1` will always be in the middle, with a width of the same size as the surrounding `left-btns`and `right-btns`, using `flex: 1;`
You can, of course, specify your `H1` to a fixed width as you did, or make it for example `flex: 2;` to have it take up 50% space instead of 33%.

[Here's the fork on CodePen.](http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/GgNjLj?editors=110)  I've removed unnecessary code.

And the code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left-btns">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <h1>center me! center me! center me! test woah asdf veasdf veasdf veasdf veasdf ve</h1>
    <div class="right-btns">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<h1>center me!</h1>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    margin: 5px;
}

h1 {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    background: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: noWrap;
}

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 1px;
    background: red;
}

.left-btns,
.right-btns {
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    background: blue;
}

.right-btns {
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: Agreed that it's close, but not EXACTLY what I want. Rather than making the center element exactly the same size as the left and right containers, I'd like the center to take up as much space as it can while still remaining centered. That's why I tried a px or % value on it. I'm starting to fear that javascript is the only way to accomplish this, and that it's just a weird side effect of flex-grow accepting only ratio values.

Comment: Removing `flex: 1;` on left-btns and right-btns will make H1 fill out all of the remaining space, if that's what you were looking for. I have a bit of a hard time understanding exactly what you want. 
Here's an example: http://codepen.io/matiasvad/pen/GgNjLj?editors=110



My first example shows a completely centered H1 using flexbox and your ellipses, etc. and by doing what I just stated it will take up all the space.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Let me try to explain better. I want the left container and right container to be the same size (flex: 1) and then the center container take up the rest of the space. If the text of the center container overflows the available space, it should show an ellipsis. As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell the center container to "take the remaining space available", right?